# WatchService Who is making change?

Tags: java, file, audit

I'd like to know who is making change while File WatchService's on. It's possible to extract user property by using Files.Ower(Path path) but I couldn't find the audit who made it within an internal network. Maybe it's not the way WatchService accepts thus does anyone have ideas on how to track or extract from the audit properties?

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok to use [Apache VFS](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/)

```
FileSystemManager manager = VFS.getManager();
FileObject file= manager.resolveFile("Your File Path");

DefaultFileMonitor fm = new DefaultFileMonitor(new YourListener());

fm.addFile(file); 

fm.start();
```

And capture the details in `YourListener` class.